# Span with text of 'Honey Script' font doesn't have any height using font-face. how to fix?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm using 'Honey Script Semibold' font. I imported it to the project using @font-face. Like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Honey Script SemiBold";
    src: url("../fonts/HoneyScript-SemiBold.eot") format("eot"),
        url("../fonts/HoneyScript-SemiBold.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/HoneyScript-SemiBold.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("../fonts/HoneyScript-SemiBold.svg#HoneyScript-SemiBold") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The problem is when i'm putting any text of this font to any inline block like span, it does show the text, and even changes the size, but it is positioned in a wrong way and it's not inside the block, but just floating randomly.

Every other font works, I imported all of them the same way. Only this font for some reason doesn't work.
Safari doesn't show the text at all. Chrome shows it just randomly floating on the page.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example that reproduces the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'honey_scriptsemibold';
    src: url('honeyscript-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('honeyscript-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```